# Make browser inaccessible when a Popup Dialog is opened until user click Accept / Decline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a Web Page where a pop-up will open on load. I want that, the user will not be able to close this pop-up until he Accept or Decline. And also user will not be able to access the browser window. Is this possible? If this is, So please provide link or code.

Comment: No, it is not possible. You cannot lock-out a user from his own local browser window.

Answer (score 2):

You can use modal instead of pop-up, show (Submit or Cancel) button only after accept or decline to close the modal.
and you cannot lock user from their own local browser window.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't really possible to prevent a user from doing anything except answer a pop-up, because you could abuse that.

However, you can force the user to answer a prompt provided he does not exit the browser window. You do this through a loop. A very basic example is the following.

```
var rep = "0";
while(rep != "1"){
var answer = prompt("Enter yes or no.")
if (answer == "yes"){
    rep = "1";
    alert("You answered yes.");
}
else if (answer == "no"){
    rep = "1";
    alert("You answered no.");
} 
else{
    alert("Answer yes or no.");
}
}
```

As said above, you can also use a modal instead of a prompt. Hope this helps.